# java - more efficient way of rendering tiles

Tags: java

I've searched for similar threads like this but couldn't find any.
I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of rendering a tile, which only uses 1 image and draws the same image in a grid to cover an area.

I'm using the code below:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    for(int r = 0; r <= tilePieces.length; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c <= tilePieces[0].length; c++) {
            try {
                tilePieces[r][c].render(g);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a tile, I also create as many tile pieces (squares) it needs and I store them in an array.
Every time the render() method of the object is called, it loops through the array and calls their render() methods, which draw the image.
There is no lag in the game, but I find this way of doing this inefficient, since I have to create a bunch of objects for one tile and call their render methods.
That's why, I tried drawing the same one image in the method above, instead of calling the render() method of each tile piece, and that caused the game to run like 1 frame per 5 seconds. Which is weird, what is the difference between calling a method to draw your image and drawing your image directly in the loop?

Comment: What is the code for the alternative approach that you're describing?

Comment: "create a bunch of objects for one tile" Please describe why this is happening.

Comment: What class is this "tile"?